# How to use MediatR with Unity in legacy ASP.NET 4.7.2?

Tags: asp.net, unity-container, mediatr, .net-4.7.2

I am working on a legacy ASP.NET application with target framework .NET 4.7.2. There is already a Unity container implemented (using [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity` v1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity/1.0.0)). Now, I want to use Mediatr with the same unity container implementation. Is this feasible?

The following NuGet packages are used:

- [Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity v1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity/1.0.0)
- [Unity v4.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/4.0.1)
- [Unity.Abstractions v3.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Abstractions/3.3.0)
- [Unity.Container v5.8.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Container/5.8.6)
- [Unity.WebForms v1.4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebForms/1.4.0)

Here is the code to register dependency with unity container

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

        // Code for dependency injection
        var diContainer = this.AddUnity();
        diContainer.RegisterType<MyServices>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
        diContainer.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
        diContainer.RegisterType<MapperConfig>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        // Services
        diContainer.RegisterType<DashboardService>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
        diContainer.RegisterType<UserVisitsService>(new TransientLifetimeManager());

        diContainer.RegisterType<MyBasePage>(new InjectionConstructor(diContainer.Resolve<MyServices>()));
        diContainer.RegisterType<UnifiedSite>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(MyServices), typeof(NavigationService)));

        // Web API controllers
        diContainer.RegisterType<Controllers.DashboardController>(new InjectionConstructor(diContainer.Resolve<DashboardService>()));
        diContainer.RegisterType<Controllers.FeedbackController>(new InjectionConstructor(diContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>()));
        diContainer.RegisterType<Controllers.UserVisitsController>(new InjectionConstructor(diContainer.Resolve<UserVisitsService>()));

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityIoCContainer(diContainer);
    }
}
```

Please guide me if anyone has used MediatR with .NET 4.7.2. If you can share a Github repository for sample code it will really help.

Comment: 4.7.2 isn't legacy but [Unity is no longer supported](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity/1.0.0). That's the real problem, not MediatR. You wouldn't have any problems registering MediatR just like you register any other service. Problems appear when you try to integrate it with the DI container using specialized DI services, which just don't exist with Unity

Comment: If you google for `MediatR Unity Container` you'll find lots of old examples, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/dcomartin/82a81fa4f5a217c50702). It may no longer work though precisely because Unity is discontinued so library authors stopped supporting it. You should seriously consider the risks of adding what is essentially a new architecture using an unsupported DI library.